# Check if group of Radio-Buttons has at least one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem with my Feedback Form. I'd like to validate with either JQuery or Javascript, that every group of radio-buttons has always one button selected before you the user can submit the form.

Here's my code from my form.html.

```
<form id='form' method='POST' action='validate.php'>
    <table>
        <!-- Table header -->
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Always</th>
            <th>Often</th>
            <th>Rarely</th>
            <th>Never</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Group One -->
        <tr>
            <th>Dummy Text 1</th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[0]' value='always'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[0]' value='often'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[0]' value='rarely'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[0]' value='never'></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Group two -->
        <tr>
            <th>Dummy Text 2</th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[1]' value='always'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[1]' value='often'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[1]' value='rarely'></th>
            <th><input class='radio' type='radio' name='item[1]' value='never'></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- End of table -->
    </table>
</form>
<button class='buttons' onclick='subForm()' name='submit'>Send Feedback</button>
<script>
    function subForm() {
        //Code
    }
</script>
```

But I dont know what I should use for checking if the radio-buttons are checked.

I tried to use `document.getElementsByName` but this gave me back `undefined` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to each group of radio buttons, and then use getelementsbyclass, or queryselectorall(compatible with older browsers). Depending on what you're trying to support, you could also consider using the HTML5 "required" attribute on your radio buttons. This will work on most browsers newer than IE8 and will require minimal coding on your part.

I can't comment so I'll clarify that the other solution posted here at the moment will not work because it checks to make sure that at least one radio button on the page has been checked, which means a user can submit an incomplete form if there are multiple groups of radio buttons. His code looks like it's functional otherwise, just create a class for each group of radio buttons.

Comment: Yes, I meant geElementsByClassName, I'm quite lazy and I generally rely on my development environment / code editor to autocomplete things like that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your best bet:

```
var selectedCount = 0;
$('.radio').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked", "checked")){
        selectedCount++;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the number of checked radio buttons:

```
$('input:radio:checked').length
```

Check if it's equal to the number of groups of radio buttons.  (In your example, two.)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ymfdL6o/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
function subForm() {

    var valid = true;
    //for every row
    jQuery("tr").each(function(idx, elem) {
        //checks only rows with radio inputs inside
        if ($(this).find('input[type=radio]').length) {
            //if there are no radios checked then form is not valid
            if (!$(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(valid);
    if (valid) {
        //submit form
    }
}
```

Variable 'valid' refers to whole form being valid (at least one radiobutton is selected in each group).

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwjm7cqw/3/).